# How to build chrome extension which paste defined strings?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, copy-paste

I am working like AdOps which means that I regularly do copy/paste. I thought that it would be a real time saver if I can find/build some tool to paste given string on command. 
I have interest in coding, but I am still a newbie and that is the reason I am writing here. Hope you'll help me.

Comment: I'm assuming by "paste" you mean "insert the string into a text input field at the cursor position." For that you'll need to use the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection_API). Once you know where the cursor is (and if it's in a text field) you'll use the usual form manipulation techniques (e.g. the `value` property) and string methods to get, modify, and replace the text. If you run into problems once you've written some code, you can come back here and [ask for help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your comment!